# Faster cosmos db query

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I followed the example from cosmos db [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/examples.py) using SQL API, but getting the data is quite slow. I'm trying to get data for one week (around 1M records). Sample code below.

```
client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(HOST, {'masterKey': KEY})
database = client.get_database_client(DB_ID)
container = database.get_container_client(COLLECTION_ID)

query = """
SELECT some columns
FROM c
WHERE columna = 'a'
and columnb >= '100'
"""

result = list(container.query_items(
         query=query, enable_cross_partition_query=True))
```

My question is, is there any other way to query data faster? Does putting the query result in list make it slow? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do.

Model your data such that you don't have to do a cross partition query. These will always take more time because your query needs to go touch more partitions for the data. You can learn more here, [Model and partition data in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example)

You can do this even faster when you only need a single item by using a point read instead of a query [read_item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.container.containerproxy?view=azure-python#read-item-item--partition-key--populate-query-metrics-none--post-trigger-include-none----kwargs-)

Comment: i'm trying to query around 1 million of records from cosmos DB and currently it's taking hours. Will it be faster if the data is partitioned correctly? Also, is it normal to query data this big using cosmos DB?

Comment: It's not normal to query millions of records in Cosmos. Are you trying to do analytics? If so you should look at [Synapse Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synapse-link). This is our integration with our analytics platform and provides integration with Apache Spark for doing big data analytics on Cosmos DB.